# Windows sessions: Process Explorer vs. Logonsessions.exe

Tags: windows, session, sysinternals

In researching a problem with an API call that is limited to particular sessions, I found some information that implied when you use runas to create a process as another user, a new security token is issued and that runs in another session (as the new user) but interacts on the running desktop.

To test that, I used runas to run Notepad as a local user while logged in as a domain user. WhenI ran Sysinternals' Process Explorer and added the Session column, it said that my domain user's processes and the new Notepad process were both session 1.

When I ran the Logonsessions utility from Sysinternals, it says my local user is running in Session 0, while my domain user is Session 1.

```
Query Session
```

...returns just my domain user on the SESSIONNAME >console.

What is the difference when I'm trying to check session information among these utilities? I seem to be missing something fundamental in understanding how Windows tracks and uses sessions and associates processes and usernames to them.

Comment: I think this is a programming question, and should probably be on Stack Overflow.  But in short, you're confusing Remote Desktop sessions with logon sessions.  They're (more or less) unrelated.